# sql statement to group by some field

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hello all my database structure is like

```
 dsid - auto increment, did,coid,eid,dcid
```

now i want to select did,coid,eid and dcid but group them by eid like when i run the while loop i should get all the values for eid1 and then for eid2 and then eid3 right now i get values in dsid descending order

i am using this query

```
 $somevari=mysqli_query($link,"select did,coid,eid,dcid from table where
 did='$variable'order by dsid desc"); //here i want to group them by eid
 while($thedatavariable=mysqli_fetch_array($somevari)){
 echo $thedatavariable['eid'];
 echo $thedatavariable['dcid'];
 }

 // i want all the values of dcid for a perticular eid and then other eid then other eid
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want the results in a particular order?  If so:

```
order by (eid = $eid) desc, eid
```

where `$eid` is your particular eid.

EDIT:

In that case, you would seem to just want:

```
order by eid
```

Comment: no i dont want all the results but order by eid (not for one eid for all the eids)